# How to convert from typedef to its constituent data type?

Tags: c++

I am new to C++ and would like to know how to convert an object of type `BYTE` into an `unsigned char`, which is what is listed as its `typedef`. `BYTE` is a Microsoft creation, and I want to use the object of it in regular C++ functions, which don't accepted `BYTE`.

Thank you.

Comment: It's an alias. No conversion is necessary because it's already the same type.

Comment: If you're interfacing with an API, use the API's typedefs.

Answer (score 3):

If `BYTE` is defined as:

```
typedef unsigned char BYTE;
```

Then they are the same type. `BYTE` is just an alias (another name) for `unsigned char` and there's no need for any further conversions, as both `unsigned char` and `BYTE` refer to the exact same type.

In case an API provides an alias such as `BYTE` it is recommended to use the alias, because future versions of the API might change the meaning of this alias. If you use the `typedef` provided by the API rather explicitly using the type it refers to, it usually leads to less changes in your code.